# javascript Array reverse повернуть много строк

Tags: javascript, массивы

Задание *Javascript Array reverse*. 
Напиши функцию `arrayReverse`, которая принимает массив строк `words`, которая содержит цифры, номера латинские символы.

Переверни строки в массиве и их порядок так, чтоб длина строк с оригинального массива не изменялась. То есть, если длина первой строки ровна **`1`**, а  последней - **`5`**, то при повороте первой строкой в массиве будет только последний символ с последней строки.

Например:  `'I', 'am', 'a', 'student!' === !tnedutsamaI`. 
А потом конечный результат должен быть: `'!', 'tn', 'e', 'dutsamaI'`

Мой код:

```js
 const arrayReverse = (words) => {
    return words.map(word => {
      const reversed = word.split('').reverse().join('');
    return reversed;
  }).reverse();
}

const result = arrayReverse(['I', 'am', 'a', 'student!']);
console.log(result);  // [ '!tneduts', 'a', 'ma', 'I' ]
```

Comment: В чём заключается вопрос?

Comment: Превратите весь массив в строку, разверните, а затем формируйте новый массив, беря нужное количество символов из строки

Answer (score 1):

Даже с енотом работает :)

```js
function solve(a) {
  return [...a.join("")]
    .reverse()
    .join("")
    .match(RegExp(a.map(x => '(' + x.replace(/./gus, '.') + ')').join(''), 'us'))
    .slice(1)
}

console.log(solve(['I', 'am', 'a', '', 'student!']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arrayReverse = (words) => {
  const full = words.join('').split('').reverse();
  return words.map(word => {
    return full.splice(0, word.length).join('');
  });
}

const result = arrayReverse(['I', 'am', 'a', 'student!']);
console.log(result); // [ '!tneduts', 'a', 'ma', 'I' ]
```

Comment: Thank You very much!

Comment: А у тебя на еноте работать не будет. А ещё асимптотика O(n*m).

Comment: @Qwertiy, "которая содержит цифры, номера латинские символы". Енотов там нет.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ну ладно, но всё равно с ними интереснее)